# Subqueries yielding more results then expected on join of two subsets

Tags: sql, dataset, left-join, sas, proc-sql

I'm receiving more ID's then possible after performing a left outer join statement on two tables.

Context: I've narrowed down two tables from larger data sets. Below are the queries found I've used to obtain IDs possible after selecting from the larger data set. I am trying to JOIN two data sets together based upon the personID. I am preforming a LEFT JOIN because I want to retain all data in the smallerset table while pairing it with data from narrowed data table.

Upon running this query on a subset of a larger data set I receive the following IDs:

```
select s.personID from st.smallerset as s;

41486
41490
41493
41496
 ...
```

Now, upon running the second query, I receive the following:

```
select r.* from st.secondlargedataset as r,
st.condition as h where r.personID=h.personID group by r.personID;
```

I receive the following queries:

```
41544
41577
41595
41605
 ...
```

So far, so good. Everything is as expected. However, when I run this next subquery as I try to join these two subsets I get unexpected results.

```
select s.personID
from st.smallerset as s left join
(select r.* from st.secondlargedataset as r,
 st.condition as h where r.personID=h.personID group by r.personID) as v on 
s.personID=v.personID;

41485
41486
41489
41490
41493
41496
41510
41512
41513
41516
```

Included in this result is data that is not include in either prior query. Specifically IDs `41485`, `41489`, `41496` et cetera. I'm clueless as to why these IDs are appearing since when I break the queries into separate queries I get the IDs I need.

Comment: Why are you mixing join styles? The subquery is using the lazy style...

Comment: st is a sas libname reference 
Forgive me, I'm learning PROC SQL and I've broken up what I need to do into individual queries that when combined via subqueries I *THOUGHT* should yield the right result.
h.personID is a separate data table that has a list of people that need to be found in secondlargedataset.

Comment: There is no reasonable way we can help solve this problem without sample data..from both data sets to be joined

Comment: Are you positive the IDs 41485, 41489, 41496 were absent from the previous result sets? None of your queries posted here contains an `ORDER BY` clause, so the "mystical" values could be e.g. somewhere at the end in one of the earlier result sets, you may have overlooked them.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem may be with this query:

```
select r.*
from st.secondlargedataset as r, st.condition as h
where r.personID=h.personID
group by r.personID;
```

The `group by` statement would be illegal in most SQL implementation, but SAS allows it (even though it's meaningless), and produces unpredictable results.

Try removing it.

Comment: You can also try shortening it further to `select r.personID
from st.secondlargedataset as r, st.condition as h
where r.personID=h.personID`, since it looks like you're discarding the rest of the fields anyway in your main select.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

`SELECT s.personID
FROM st.smallerset AS s
WHERE s.personID IN (
    SELECT r.personID
    FROM st.secondlargedataset AS r, st.condition AS h
    WHERE r.personID = h.personID
    GROUP BY r.personID
)`

OR

`SELECT s.personID
FROM st.smallerset AS s
WHERE s.personID IN (
    SELECT r.personID 
    FROM st.secondlargedataset AS r 
    INNER JOIN st.condition AS h ON r.personID = h.personID 
    GROUP BY r.personID
)`

Comment: This does not yield the expected results since the table of st.smallerset is not kept in tack. In fact, there are less observations than the initial query I constructed. I'm trying something else.

Comment: The result of that query is: 
41577
41595
41605
41607
                                                 41636
                                                 41666
                                                 41672
                                                 41727
                                                 41755